# Rserve as a NT Service

Tags: windows, r

I am trying to start Rserve.exe as an NT Service; however, any time I try to run

```
     C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc create rserve binpath= "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x6
     4\Rserve.exe" DisplayName= "Rserve" start= auto
     [SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

When I try to start the service in Windows services I receive the error

```
     Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Comment: Is it supported as a windows service? I find no evidence that it is. What user account are you running the service under?

Comment: I've had a quick look at the source code, and `Rserve.exe` is definitely not a service.  You could use NSSM (see http://nssm.cc) to run it in a service session though.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Hi I was wondering if you could point me to the right direction as to what qualifies a program as a NT service runnable application. For example you mentioned you looked at the source code, how can you tell that the source code contains no "hooks" to bind as an NT service?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: In particular, the main function of a service calls `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`.